# RxJS: Converting Node.js sockets into Observables and merge them into one stream

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I'm trying to convert Node's sockets into streams using RxJS. The goal is to have each socket create it's own stream and have all streams merge into one. As new sockets connect, a stream is created with `socketStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'message')`.

Then the stream is merged into a master stream with something like

`mainStream = mainStream.merge(socketStream)`

This appears to work fine, the problem is that after 200-250 client connections, the server throws `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

I have sample server and client code that demonstrates this behavior on a gist here:
[Sample Server and Client](https://gist.github.com/astanciu/3e7f65b1c8b6b7508c26)

I suspect that as clients connect/disconnect, the main stream doesn't get cleaned up properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are merging your `Observable` recursively. Every time you do

```
cmdStream = cmdStream.merge(socketStream);
```

You are creating a new `MergeObservable/MergeObserver` pair.

Taking a look at the [source](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/perf/operators/mergeconcat.js), you can see that what you are basically doing with each subscription is subscribing to each of your previous streams in sequence so it shouldn't be hard to see that at around 250 connections your call stack is probably at least 1000 calls deep.

A better way to approach this would be to convert use the `flatMap` operator and think of your connections as creating an `Observable` of `Observables`.

```
//Turn the connections themselves into an Observable
var connections = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(server, 'connection', 
                    socket => new JsonSocket(socket));

connections
  //flatten the messages into their own Observable
  .flatMap(socket => {
    return Rx.Observable.fromEvent(socket.__socket, 'message')
           //Handle the socket closing as well
           .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.fromEvent(socket.__socket, 'close'));
  }, (socket, msg) => { 
    //Transform each message to include the socket as well.
    return { socket : socket.__socket, data : msg}; 
  })
  .subscribe(processData, handleError);
```

The above I haven't tested but should fix your SO error.

I would probably also question the overall design of this. What exactly are you gaining by merging all the `Observable`s together? You are still differentiating them by passing the socket object along with the message so it would seem these could all be distinct streams.

Comment: Oh man, not only did this solve my issue, it turns the connections into a stream too (I thought of doing this but didn't understand flatMap correctly) AND does it in under 10 lines of code (from my version of 100+ which I cleaned for the gist).  THANK YOU! ++beer

Comment: Oh and regarding the design, as you can tell I'm just getting into Rx stuff so this was partly an exercise in "everything is a stream" thinking and also with the intent to later be able to buffer and setup some back pressure if needed. Figured if all incoming messages are in one stream, the buffering would be more straight forward.

Comment: You are very welcome. It's not a hard and fast rule, and it may very well be the case for your scenario that merging makes more sense. Either way welcome to the beauty of streams!